# Solve $y'-2ty=3t^3y^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve $y'-2ty=3t^3y^2$

$y=0$ is a solution. So letting $y\ne0$ divide by $y$.

$\frac{y'}{y^2}-\frac{2t}{y}=3t^2$

Doing change of variables we get $-u'-2tu=3t^3$

And after that book says it is linear equation and solution is

$u(t)=c e^{-t^2}+\frac{3}{2}(t^2-1)$

Will be glad if you can help out where this formula come from.

Comment: For primes you should use `'` or `^{\prime}`, not just `\prime`.

Comment: My Real Analysis textbook states and proves the following theorem, which can be used against $-u'-2tu=3t^3$.  Assume that $P$ and $Q$ are continuous functions on an open interval $I$.  Assume that $a \in I$ and $b \in \Bbb{R}.$  Then there is exactly one function $f(x)$ on $I$ that satisfies $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$ with $f(a) = b$.  Namely, $$f(x) = be^{-A(x)} + e^{-A(x)}\int_a^x Q(t)e^{A(t)}dt$$ with $$A(x) = \int_a^x P(t)dt.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-u'-2tu=3t^3$$
Multiply by $e^{t^2}$:
$$(e^{t^2}u)'=-3t^{3}e^{t^2}$$
$$(e^{t^2}u)'=-\dfrac 32t^{2}(e^{t^2})'$$
Integrate both sides. And integrate by part the RHS.

Comment: Only I am getting $u = c*e^{-t^2}-\frac{3}{2}(t^2-1)$

Comment: Your answer is correct @unit1991 looks like there is a sign mistake in the book.